# In the book of Job, it suggests that angels sin. Do they?

Tags: exegesis, sin, angels

In the 4th chapter in the book of Job, it states in verses 17 and 18 that: ‘Can mortal man be in the right before[b] God? Can a man be pure before his Maker? Even in his servants he puts no trust, and his angels he charges with error.'

"His angels he charges with error"? Do they sin or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a Christian perspective based on the New Testament.

Yes, angels can and did sin.

In [2 Peter 2:4 (A.V.)](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=2Pe&c=2&t=KJV#4), it is written,

> For if God spared not the **angels** that **sinned**, but cast [them] down to hell, and delivered [them] into chains of darkness, to be reserved unto judgment;

Hopefully that settles the matter.

Comment: Nice concise, well supported answer!

Comment: It may be notable to mention that an angel's sins are both immediate are unforgivable, due its purely spiritual nature. (At least according to Catholic belief.) That is, when an angel is created, it proceeds directly to heaven, never to sin, or directly to hell. Also notable, the Church (and I think most Christians) call angels who have sinned **demons**.